# Users with less than 150 rep getting the Constituent badge? Voting?

Tags: discussion, election, badges

Uh... how? Shouldn't people with less than 150 rep be unable to vote? But they appear on the [Constituent list](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/badges/95/constituent).

Waiting to hear whether these are votes - or if they're only getting the badge without voting.

A few of these were our sock-puppety friend - and they've been [cleaned up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184863/173986). But still.

---

[image: Election]

Comment: Hmm, I think I have more than 21 rep :) I guess Byte56 is a common name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those users had more than 150 reputation at some point, and lost it again when some of their posts where removed. That is the reason they were able to vote.

Comment: Beat me to it. That's it exactly. Many of these were around the ~300 level prior to deleting their positively scored posts over time. It's tedious, but I'm going through it now.

Comment: Makes sense. To be fair: They appeared from the outside to have naturally low rep - because the evidence of them ever having been upvoted was removed.

Comment: @TimPost Do their votes get removed when they drop below 150 rep after voting?

Comment: @NathanReed No, but account removal does remove them (which is what I did).